# Handling changes in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have little problem with handling data modifications in my datagridView.
I bind a DataSource to the datagridview just like this:

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var customersQuery = new ObservableCollection<Payment>(context.Payments);
        customersQuery.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(customerQuery_Changed);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = customersQuery };

    }
    OrdersDataModelContainer context = new OrdersDataModelContainer();
```

and I'm handling changes like below:

```
    private void customerQuery_Changed(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (Payment p in e.NewItems)
            {
                context.Payments.Add(p);
            }
        }
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (Payment p in e.OldItems)
            {

                context.Payments.Remove(p);
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Remove works but Add not so well. Add action is called when I click on the new row co I'm getting exception because cell are empty. How in simply way I can change behavior to call Add after inserting is over and i switch to next row?
Another problem is with modifications  of existing data rows. They are updated in database only after inserting new data.

Can anyone give me solution or point where I should search for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CollectionChanged insert new empty elements.
On PropertyChanged insert values to elements.

Comment: I tried to find binding option, that says "Update collection on unfocus from new row" not right after you've add one, but don't see such. Create empty entities when empty row appears on grid, update values, when they are updated looks elegant enough.

Comment: Yeah. You are right but then I must handle one more option. Delete when someone decided to add newRow and then leaves it empty :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following class:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public event CollectionChangeEventHandler RealCollectionChanged;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            this.OnRealCollectionChanged(e.NewItems[0]);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnRealCollectionChanged(object element)
    {
        if (this.RealCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            this.RealCollectionChanged(this, new CollectionChangeEventArgs(CollectionChangeAction.Add, element));
        }
    }
}
```

This event will be thrown after the standard one, however this is the latest point it can be thrown at.

Comment: Thanks! To be honest I can't understand this code snippet now but will read about it :)